# Find dd.mm.yyyy in html

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all dates formatted as dd.mm.yyyy in html source such as:

```
     <span id="publisher" itemprop="Publisher" data-source="LE MONDE">Le Monde</span>
 |    <time datetime="2018-05-30T10:44:42+02:00"
        itemprop="datePublished">30.05.2018 &agrave; 10h44</time>
 • Mis à jour le
<time datetime="2018-05-31T13:54:38+02:00"
        itemprop="dateModified">31.05.2018 &agrave; 13h54</time>
        |
<span class="signature_article">
Par      <span itemprop="author" class="auteur txt2_120">            <a class="auteur" target="_blank" href="/journaliste/anne-sophie-faivre-le-cadre/">Anne-Sophie Faivre Le Cadre</a>
        </span>
</span>

</p>
```

I've been looking around SO and none of the solutions worked for my case.
For instance:

```
^\s*(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\.(1[012]|0?[1-9])\.((?:19|20)\d{2})\s*
```

Which works on the string "ajhajashsja 31.05.2018" doesn't work on the html above which contains the same date. How come?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:-

```
import re

#documentString is the string representing your html text.
print re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{4}", documentString ,re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
['30.05.2018', '31.05.2018']
```

Comment: Based on the asker's example, he wants to match _only_ valid dates, and make the century prefix optional (at least as long as it's 19 or 20). This will match a lot more than that.

Comment: @glibdud, i agree that's a valid point, if required, regex can be adjusted accordingly. However, the user hasn't asked for anything related with Year range or something in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `^\s*(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\.(1[012]|0?[1-9])\.((?:19|20)\d{2})\s*`, matches any line started with no or some blanks, then immediately a date you need, then ends with no or some blanks.

The problem is caused by the "stared with no or some blanks, then immediately". Remove the beginning `^` will solve the problem, since your test case contains date neither at the beginning of line, or after some blanks.

Edit: According to my test, I can't find any result corresponding to the end of question

> Which works on the string "ajhajashsja 31.05.2018"

I don't know whether this is my coding error or the question's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps to get YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
2[0-9]{3}-(0[1-9])|(1[1-2])-([0-2][0-9])|([3][01])
```

In case of DD-MM-YYYY use following.

```
([0-2][0-9])|([3][01])-(0[1-9])|(1[1-2])-2[0-9]{3}
```

Or use `\.` in place of `-` in above ones in case your text has `.` in them.

Comment: Like several other answers, this will match more than what the asker is looking for (things that look like dates but aren't valid), and won't allow the century prefix to be optional like he attempted to do.

Comment: @glibdud, how about now? Please do let me know?

Comment: Better, except I think you need some more parens around each group to delimit how far the `|` operators reach.

Comment: @glibdud, sure cool, feel free to edit it to make this post better please.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the carrot `^` at the beginning of your pattern, as that will only find a match at the beginning of the line.

> **^** asserts position at start of a line

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's regex module

```
import re
a = """
<span id="publisher" itemprop="Publisher" data-source="LE MONDE">Le Monde</span>
 |    <time datetime="2018-05-30T10:44:42+02:00"
        itemprop="datePublished">30.05.2018 &agrave; 10h44</time>
 • Mis à jour le
 <time datetime="2018-05-31T13:54:38+02:00"
        itemprop="dateModified">31.05.2018 &agrave; 13h54</time>
        |
 <span class="signature_article">
 Par      <span itemprop="author" class="auteur txt2_120">            <a class="auteur" target="_blank" href="/journaliste/anne-sophie-faivre-le-ca
dre/">Anne-Sophie Faivre Le Cadre</a>
         </span>
 </span>

 </p>
 """
match=re.findall(r'(\d{2,2}.\d{2,2}.\d{4,4})',a)
print match
['30.05.2018', '31.05.2018']
```

match will contains an array of all matched string

Comment: Like several other answers, this will match more than what the asker is looking for (things that look like dates but aren't valid), and won't allow the century prefix to be optional like he attempted to do.

Comment: not understand exactly, asker is looking for all the dates that match the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, and that's all above code do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. I tested at https://regex101.com/.

```
[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: you need to change from `.` to `\.` as a single dot means any character so by escaping it you will tell regex to match exact DOT itself.

Comment: Sure, this will match what the asker is looking for, but it'll match a lot of things he's _not_ looking for, too.

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13